# Is it possible to "loosely" define an object using React.PropTypes.shape?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using [React.PropTypes.shape](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#prop-validation) is it possible to say that an object must have fields x,y,z, but can also have as many arbitrary other fields as it likes?

I would like to ensure than an object has at least a few required fields, but I want the user to be able to pass in any number of additional key/values into the object as well.

Comment: You can add as many fields as you want. `React.PropTypes.shape` does not care for additional unspecified fields.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Make that an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add as many fields as you want. `React.PropTypes.shape` does not care for additional unspecified fields.